# Angular 2 <mat-expansion-panel> expand and collapse all

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894 ... 
Here is a problem: When I expand item by the hand, "collapse all" won't work (the same when I "expand all", then collapse manually items, "expand all" button won't work).
Any ideas for the fix?

Comment: yes, there is issue if manually collapse or un-collapse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem here is all material component/directive have an OnPush detection strategy. So if the reference of the input doesn't change ( for Object/Array, or the value of the primitive for string/number/boolean ) the component is not re-rendered.

In your case, if you expand all panels you set `allExpandState` to true, but even if you manually close a panel the `allExpandState` stay at true. So if you click again to expand all, the `allExpandState` stay to true and the panels are not re-rendered.

Here is a forked [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49230894-jztrbd) with a solution (certainly not the only available).

The main topic is to get all instance of MatExpansionPanel with

```
@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) viewPanels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

And then in the `allExpandState` setter to manually open or close all the panels with

```
this.viewPanels.forEach(p => value ? p.open() : p.close());
```